# Encoding issue: Some letters disappear when automated typing into web input (Python 2.7.9, Webbrowser, Chrome, Windows)

Tags: python, encoding, automation

I am automating web form input via Python 2.7.9, Webbrowser, Chrome (Windows). A website has cp1251 encoding.
I'm trying to send cyrillic text to the "input type=text" element.
But the resulting text always misses 15 of 33 letters of the cyrillic alphabet.

```
text = "(Cyrillic text)"
obj_name = browser.find_element_by_id("obj_name")
obj_name.send_keys(text)
```

I tried to change file encoding (utf8, cp1251). Also I tried to post text in Unicode (u"Cyrillic text"). I tried using **text = unicode(text, "cp1251")** before sending text to input. None of this helped to solve the problem.

This problem appears with only one website. But I can't find out where it goes wrong.

What can be the root of the problem? What should I probably check out / change?

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as unicode and then encode. Then you can work with it somehow

```
text = u"Здравствуй, мир!".encode("cp1251")
```